# Is it possible to prevent the installation of a required package?

Tags: apt

If you install a program which depends on a number of other packages which are
not installed, then `apt-get` automatically installs those dependencies. In
allmost all cases this is the desired behaviour.

But now and then I have a case where I don't want to install a package which is
marked as required but which is not really needed to use the program I actually
want to install.

Example:

- I want to install the program `logwatch`
- the `logwatch` package depends on the installation of a mail transfer agent (MTA)
- `logwatch` can be used without a MTA
- I don't want to install a MTA

I know I could install the program from source. But I want to know if `apt-get`
provides a method to prevent the installation of a dependency (without breaking
the whole package management system).

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible without hacking in some way into the package management system, I think.

The reason is that `logwatch` declare `postfix`, or alternatively `mail-transport-agent`, as a *dependency*, and not as a *recommend*. If the package can work also without an MTA, this strong dependency could be a bug.

Also installing through `dpkg` do not solve, because the ignored dependencies will continue to pop-up at next `apt-get` operation.

A possible way to follow could be to download and modify the package to remove the *offending* dependency. It is not that hard to realize, but I will give details if you're iterested.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried this on `logwatch` itself, but generally ignoring dependencies is done like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=postfix the_package.deb
```

There is no way of doing this via `apt` that I know of.

EDIT: *enzotib* is right, `apt` will complain at a later stage of a missing dependency. *Apt-pinning* or changing the dependencies in the `deb` package might be a better way.

Comment: Apt pinning with preference -1?

Comment: Apt-pinning is explained at https://askubuntu.com/questions/75895/how-to-forbid-a-specific-package-to-be-installed - For me it only worked for recommends - not depends.