# How to forbid a specific package to be installed?

Tags: apt, package-management

Can I configure Ubuntu to never install a specific package even if it is required by another package I install?

Comment: You cannot install a package without its dependencies, unless you want to break your system.

Comment: @enzotib, first of all you're wrong: package dependencies can be redundant. there are numerous examples, or you can have installed an equivalent of a required package another way (for example I have openjdk-6 installed as it is required by all the java applications in the repos, but I never actually use openjdk-6, I set up everything to use openjdk-7 or Oracle JDK 7 instead). And the second thing - I didn't say I want the dependant package to be installed - it can just throw an error in this case, I just want to make sure a particular package is never installed anyway.

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://askubuntu.com/q/59083).

Answer (score 41):

As in Debian we can use [apt-pinning](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) for version and installation control [in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) too.

To block the installation of a given package we may put the following lines in `/etc/apt/preferences`

```
Package: <nameofpackage>
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1
```

By giving a negative priority for this pin we will block the installation of `<nameofpackage>` from not further specified origin, i.e. our local repository. Of course we can use apt-pinning to pin a certain package version or specific origin.

Before you proceed it is strongly recommended to read the documentation given above and the manpage from [apt_preferences](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/apt_preferences) because errors in these files are not checked by apt and if they occur may break your package management.

For an alternative, and to prevent updating of a given package see:

- [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Comment: Do you know if this could work in Ubuntu 12.04? [Another question](http://askubuntu.com/q/258916/62483) is reporting that maybe it doesn't work.

Comment: @Lucio: sure - it still works; just tested it to work in 12.10 too.

Comment: In the `Package:`-line, you can list multiple packages separated with spaces, like this: Package: metacity metacity-common libmetacity-private0a. (Seems like patterns like Package: metacity* are also possible)

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 `Pin: origin ""` didn't work for me, but `Pin: release *` did.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, this seems to be the only way to prevent a package to be installed. The `apt-mark hold` solution described elsewhere does not work exactly as expected: sometimes it will work _once_ (i.e. for the _next_ upgrade), but then the 'hold' gets 'released' and `apt` will try to install it again... the only thing that seems to consistently work is adding files inside `/etc/apt/preferences.d` with `Pin: release *`. It's worth reading the man page: there are serious limitations in the filename; and you can use multiple packages in the same configuration file as well as use wildcards.

Comment: For me this only worked for Recommends - not for Depends (Also 20.04).

Comment: This does work for `apt`, but does not seem to affect the `snap` unfortunately (which is the default installer on 20.04 if I understand well).

Comment: @nocibambi: for snaps see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131182/how-can-i-disable-automatic-update-for-a-single-snap-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 6):

I have a package that keeps sneaking back in and breaking git

```
sudo apt-mark hold libgnutls-deb0-28
```

should prevent that package from being installed

Comment: This is not a reliable solution, especially when you have to upgrade your distro. The good solution is already provided: https://askubuntu.com/a/76075/93706

Answer (score 2):

In debian you can block a package, and that package wont upgrade anymore

```
# echo name_of_package hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

but I'm not sure that you can forbid

Comment: I just tried it on Ubuntu 15.10 (wily) and it didn't block the package; just gave me a warning `package not in database`

Comment: This is not a reliable solution, especially when you have to upgrade your distro. The good solution is already provided: https://askubuntu.com/a/76075/93706