# avoid installing some packages from metapackage

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to install `xubuntu-desktop` (a very large metapackage) but leaving out some of the packages on it (around 10). The current way I do this is in two steps: 1) install metapackage, and 2) purge unwanted packages. I wonder whether there is a more efficient and clean method to do this.

I thought `apt-get` would accept an instruction like *install this except these* but very surprisingly it seem not.

A potential solution would be to run the command `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`, then select **No**, and copy all the packages listed in the terminal, manually deleting the undesired ones. However this could be even more time consuming than the two-step procedure mentioned earlier, also risking to end up with bad dependencies.

Any ideas on how to make this in one simple command-line instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could script the task. I'm pretty sure I posted this elsewhere, but can't find it now. First, create a file with the packages you don't want. For example:

```
$ cat dont-want.txt
memtest86+
wireless-tools
firefox
evince
```

Then parse the output of `apt-cache depends`:

```
apt-cache depends xubuntu-desktop | awk '$1 == "Depends:" {print $2}' | grep -vFf dont-want.txt
```

This should include the packages on which the metapackage directly depends, without the packages you excluded. Then you can use `xargs` to install:

```
apt-cache depends xubuntu-desktop | 
  awk '$1 == "Depends:" {print $2}' | 
  grep -vFf dont-want.txt |
  sudo xargs apt-get install
```

If the unwanted package is not a direct dependency, you would need to use [`apt-rdepends`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/apt-rdepends.1.html) instead of `apt-cache depends`.

You can also use Apt Pinning to enforce the ban: [How to forbid a specific package to be installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75895/how-to-forbid-a-specific-package-to-be-installed)