# How do I exclude specific packages from installation with apt-get?

Tags: apt, package-management, metapackages

I would like to exclude specific packages from installation with `apt-get`, that is, install a metapackage without the list of specific packages, preferably with one invocation of `apt-get`.

For example, in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS command-line, I am installing MATE desktop environment. In 14.04 LTS MATE is not an official flavour, so I'm adding a PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common # need them for 'apt-add-repository'
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
sudo apt-get update
```

then installing:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg mate-core --no-install-recommends
```

Even without the recommended extras, `mate-core` installs 3 terminal emulators: `xterm`, `uxterm` and `mate-terminal` <sub>, the latter lacking proper fonts while installed in this minimal configuration.</sub>

Suppose I decide that 3 terminal programs would be too many and I'd like to install `xorg` and `mate-core` *without* `xterm` and `mate-terminal`. I could do

```
sudo apt-get install xorg mate-core --no-install-recommends
sudo apt-get purge xterm mate-terminal
```

but is it possible to do this in one go? Is there some syntax like

```
sudo apt-get install xorg mate-core --without xterm mate-terminal
```

Comment: Are you sure you can remove `xterm` and `mate-terminal`? In 15.04, `mate-terminal` is a hard dependency of `mate-desktop-environment-core`, which is a hard dependency of `mate-core`, and I suppose the PPA `mate-terminal` doesn't provide `x-terminal-emulator` (which the package in 15.04 does).

Comment: [Maybe you're right](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11067866/), unless an asterisk next to package names means something special here. Also, surprisingly little space is going to be freed. Anyway, my question is about removing whatever can be removed, say, `XTerm` and maybe `UXTerm` (I'm not sure what package name for the latter is)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://askubuntu.com/questions/75895/how-to-forbid-a-specific-package-to-be-installed

Comment: @Seth Not quite: I would like if there would be some syntax like `sudo apt-get install xorg mate-core --without xterm mate-terminal`

Comment: If you use `aptitude` (or some graphical package manager), you can (de)select which packages to install, and if one results in a broken dependency, an explanation will (usually) be given.

Answer (score 7):

So, [mate-core](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages) *depends* on `mate-desktop-environment-core` which in turn *depends* on `mate-terminal`. A *depend* cannot be broken easily. Nor `apt-get` nor `aptitude` supports a `--without` or `--exclude` option and "holding" the packages won't help:

```
$ echo "mate-terminal hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
$ sudo apt-get install mate-core
[...]
Some packages could not be installed...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
```

Sure, one can use `dpkg --force-depends` to install a package, but that's maybe not what you want.

A possibility would be to fullfill the `Depends:` flag with a dummy package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install equivs
$ equivs-control mate-terminal
$ vi mate-terminal
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2
Package: mate-terminal
Version: 1.8.0
Description: Dummy package for mate-terminal
:x

$ equivs-build mate-terminal
$ sudo dpkg -i mate-terminal_1.8.0_all.deb
```

Now `mate-core` should be able to install w/o `mate-terminal`. Repeat the same for other packages to be excluded.

Admittedly this is quite an effort and a `--without` option would be nice. Maybe a [wishlist bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt) can be opened to provide such functionality in the future, but I somehow doubt that this will be implemented.

However, a more realistic option would be to petition the [PPA owner](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev) to provide another meta package for MATE with lesser `Depends` packages set.

Answer (score 6):

There's a special `apt` syntax for scenarios like this: appending a hyphen (minus sign) to a package will remove/not install it, so the closest to your `sudo apt-get install xorg mate-core --without xterm mate-terminal`
is
`sudo apt-get install xorg mate-core xterm- mate-terminal-`
(spotted on https://askubuntu.com/a/1011439/182923)

It will not help in this case, as you will run into

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mate-desktop-environment-core : Depends: mate-terminal (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed                                                                        
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

but it seems to be the answer to your specific question. So for reference, this cross-post.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `aptitude` or a graphical package manager (Synaptic, etc.), then you can unselect which packages should be installed *as long as* it doesn't cause a dependency issue.

In the case of `aptitude`, before installing a package (in the graphical view), it will show you why a dependent package is being installed. In my case, I use KDE, and so don't have any MATE packages. If I tell it to install `mate-core`, I get the following:

[image]

Notice that `mate-core` is marked as being manually installed, and many other packages are being installed. For the `mate-terminal` package, in the bottom, it says, "`mate-desktop-environment-core` [universe] depends on `mate-terminal` (>= 1.0.0)". Going over to the entry for `mate-desktop-environment-core`,

[image]

"`mate-core` [universe] depends on `mate-desktop-environment-core` (>= 1.8.0+9)". This is why `mate-terminal` is being installed.

If, instead, a recommended package is being installed (rather than something that is dependent on another package), `aptitude` will tell you so, and you can tell it not to install that package without any broken dependencies. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another method

Download main package which depend on the other. Extract the package, remove the unwanted dependencies, repack it. Now open the new package with *gdebi* package installer. It will install new dependencies for you.

- List of depencies can be found at *DEBIAN* /*control* ->  **depends**
- For help on repacing deb see my answer on *how to create a PPA*