# How can I install Iceweasel in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: firefox, drm, iceweasel

How can I install Iceweasel in Ubuntu 15.04, and keep assured that it will not be replaced by Firefox in the future upgrades?

It is actually quite weird that `sudo apt-get install iceweasel` installs Firefox instead of Iceweasel on Ubuntu 15.04. I think that is not supposed to happen.

The reason is that Firefox started to use DRM - which I don't want.

Comment: You can install iceweasel by downloading the [debian version](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=iceweasel) and installing the relevant deb packages.

Comment: DRM software is not incluided in Firefox itself, there isn't even a Linux build yet. https://leomca.github.io/2014/05/15/Mozilla-and-DRM.html

Answer (score 1):

[**Iceweasel**](https://wiki.debian.org/Iceweasel) web browser is a fork from Firefox for the purpose: backporting of security fixes to declared Debian stable version and no inclusion of trademarked Mozilla artwork.

Beyond that, they will be basically identical.

- To get started, press `Ctrl+Alt+T` on your keyboard to open terminal. When it opens, run command below to add the PPA:

  ```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dirk-computer42/c42-backport
  ```
- Then update and install the browser:

  ```
     sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install iceweasel
  ```

Hope it will work.

Comment: it didn’t work, it's installing Firefox instead as well... :S

Comment: i needed to block firefox by editing /etc/apt/preferences
[
Package: <nameofpackage>
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1
]
(information from http://askubuntu.com/questions/75895/how-to-forbid-a-specific-package-to-be-installed )

and from http://ppa.launchpad.net/dirk-computer42/c42-backport/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iceweasel/ i needed to download libmozjs24d, xulrunner-24.0 and iceweasel, and install them one by one via gdebi, and on synaptic do menu:package/lockversion on each of them

Comment: i won't recommend this solution because it suggests version 24.3.0 which is out of date!

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible to add the repository of the [Debian Mozilla team](http://mozilla.debian.net/)...

if nothing else is working you can maybe download and install the [iceweasel-packages](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=iceweasel&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) manually. BUT you have to update it every time yourself!