# How do I block Zeitgeist from ever being installed on my system?

Tags: apt, zeitgeist

How do I block Zeitgeist from ever being installed on my system?

I find it quite frustrating that this is continually trying to sneak in the back door. I do not want this on my computers, ever though there seems to be packages that insist on making it a dependency when it is not required.

I just found the Zeitgeist-Datahub service running on my system and I am NOT happy about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to forbid a specific package to be installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75895/how-to-forbid-a-specific-package-to-be-installed)

Answer (score 0):

First you get your Ubuntu system to tty1 by pressing on CTRL+ALT+F1, then run the following:

```
killall zeitgeist
sudo apt-get purge zeitgeist*
```

Then block the Zeitgeist package by running:

```
vim /etc/apt/preferences
```

If you don't have vim run:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

On vim, you press I to insert the new line.
Then you can add the following:

```
Package: zeitgeist 
Pin: origin "" 
Pin-Priority: -1
```

Then press ESC to go to command mode, type :w and wait for writing progress, and when finished, type :q

Go to GUI Mode again by either:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Or press CTRL+ALT+F7 to get back to GUI, and then restart your computer.