# APT - Install packages incl. recommended without an explicit one

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to install multiple packages with `apt-get`:

```
listOfPackages="packa packb packc"
listOfBlocked="badone"
apt-get install $listOfPackages
```

The selected packages recommend multiple packages. I want to install all but one of the recommended packages.

Is this possible? How? (Something like `apt-get install $listOfPackages --BLOCKED=$listOfBlocked` would be nice.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to forbid a specific package to be installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75895/how-to-forbid-a-specific-package-to-be-installed)

Comment: Not the same question, but what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To make a package unavailable for installation, upgrading or uninstallation, you can use the command:

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package>
```

To make a package available for update

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package>
```