# Where, and how, do I install multiple packages stored in a local directory?

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, repository, source-packages

I've found several posts about mass installing Linux packages with one command [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874611/installing-multiple-packages-at-the-same-time?newreg=7d19af299a5a4c428729f5718099ce01), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39497/apt-get-install-multiple-packages-without-stopping), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089177/apt-install-packages-incl-recommended-without-an-explicit-one).

Here's my situation. I'm in a 3rd-world country right now with limited internet access. I want to know if there's a way to download a bunch of packages, store them somewhere, and write a little bash script to mass install them.

Is there a website that has a repository where I can do a one-time download of these *permanently* instead of having to use a bunch of data doing "apt-get" every time I try out a fresh installation of a Linux distro?

After I download these is there a way I can easily install them all these deb or tar files by writing a little bash script?

Comment: `sudo apt-get download <package_name>` will down the package but won't install so you could write a script to download all files in a text file with the names of the packages passed to that commad! Then to install them from some directory you put them into do `sudo apt-get install *.deb` in that folder where they all are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download them all:

1. Create a text file with their names, one on each line.
2. Create a folder to store these package files:

   ```
   mkdir ~/packages_store
   ```
3. Read and download the `deb` file of each package on that list:

   ```bsh
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   # Change to the storage folder
   # or exit if it doesn't exist
   cd ~/packages_store || exit

   # Remove blank lines first then read
   # from file

   sed '/^$/d' "$1" | while read -r line; do            
       apt-get download "$line"
   done
   ```

   - Usage: `chmod +x myscript.sh`, then `sudo ./myscript.sh /path/to/text_with_packagenames`
4. To install all:

   1. Change into that folder `cd ~/packages_store`
   2. Run installer:

      ```
      sudo apt-get install *.deb
      ```

Hopefully this is what you’re looking for!

Comment: Could you explain what your `sed | while` block does? Wouldn’t `< "$1" xargs apt-get download` do the work?

Comment: It removes spacd's that OP might add. And that works please add an answer using that method.

Comment: And @melebius when dealing with an inexperienced it's best to take it slow break it down so they learn and improve at their own pace!

Comment: Thank you for the script. Can you clarify how/where I can get these deb packages? I'm running Bodhi 4, and I think it's a Xenial Ubuntu, but when I go to the package list on this site nothing is there: packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/allpackages

Answer (score 0):

Here is the repository of [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/).
Search desired package with ubuntu flavour and install it with apt procedure.

Comment: I don't understand what to do in that site. I'm running Bodhi 4, and I think it's a Xenial Ubuntu, but when I go to the package list nothing is there: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/allpackages

Comment: Search for the desired package that you want from the list, like that I have searched for "Twitter Login in Gnome": https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/account-plugin-twitter. And then download (all) from your nearest server mirror location.