# What happens to /usr/bin/parallel if I install the moreutils on top of the parallel package?

Tags: bash, package-management

I have `moreutils` installed which provides `/usr/bin/parallel`, which is not useful for me. If I now want to install the `parallel` package (GNU Parallel) I have learnt from [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/917577/978559) that it would rename the existing `/usr/bin/parallel` of `moreutils` to `/usr/bin/parallel.moreutils`.

I was wondering what would happen if the opposite is done. For example, I have the `parallel` package installed and later on someone uninstalls `moreutils` and then reinstalls it again, will it rename `/usr/bin/parallel` to `/usr/bin/parallel.gnu` or what name would it get?

And if it does the renaming, how to avoid that?

My current Ubuntu version is:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available. 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 
LTS Release: 18.04 
Codename: bionic
```

I also use Ubuntu 16.04 on other machines.

Comment: I *think* the answer is no, it does not rename GNU `parallels` to `parallels.gnu` because the renaming is done by the `parallel` package itself, using the `dpkg-divert` mechanism. There's a long thread involving the `moreutils` maintainer here: [parallel: /usr/bin/parallel conflicts with moreutils' parallel](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=749355)

Comment: Just tried you are right. It does not change `parallel` to another name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Ubuntu 18.04 and later

If you install any one of the packages, it will provide `/usr/bin/parallel`. If you install both **in any order**, you will get

- `/usr/bin/parallel` with GNU Parallel
- `/usr/bin/parallel.moreutils` with `moreutils`’ `parallel`

See: [How can I install GNU Parallel alongside Moreutils on Ubuntu/Debian?](https://superuser.com/a/1253492/748149)

#### Ubuntu 16.04

It will not be automatically renamed. I can’t test it, but my guess is that either will the `parallel` package be removed or – worse – the file will be overwritten.

A workaround to prevent the `moreutils` package from being accidentally removed or installed is a hold:

> **hold** is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.

```
sudo apt-mark hold moreutils
```

This will prevent any *automatic* installation, however it can easily be overridden with `apt-get`’s `--ignore-hold` flag.

A similar alternative (but maybe not so easy to override?) is pinning as explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/76075/507051) to the relevant question [How to forbid a specific package to be installed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75895/507051).