# Satisfy dependency with manual compile and install

Tags: apt, dependencies, compiling, cmake

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. My coding project needs cmake 3.18 support, so I do a manual compile and install. Now I want to remove version 3.10 that came as a dependency from another package, WITHOUT removing said package. Is there a way?

What i found so far was a way to prevent the install of cmake via apt, but I do not know if this helps me here: [How to forbid a specific package to be installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75895/how-to-forbid-a-specific-package-to-be-installed)

Thanks!

Comment: *Why* do you need to remove the 3.10 version? what specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I think I was looking for a way to only have the one, true version installed. I do not trust unix to always find the version I want, when there are different version available. I also want to find packages that hardcoded call for a specific version for example.