# Is there any alternative to apt-listbugs for Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

On debian `apt-listbugs` is used to report bugs, it can be used also to prevent a package from being installed by setting a pin priority in `apt-listbugs` preferences.

Is there any alternative to `apt-listbugs` for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is much help, but bug reporting in Ubuntu is: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs If you don't want something to be installed, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/75895/how-to-forbid-a-specific-package-to-be-installed

Comment: Having an Ubuntu version of apt-listbugs would be great. In the meantime I make do with the Debian version as well. apt-listbugs saved my skin many times.

Answer (score 1):

On my hirsute I downloaded the .deb for Debian 11 :

[apt-listbugs_0.1.35_all.deb](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt-listbugs/apt-listbugs_0.1.35_all.deb)

Install it the usual way you prefer (`dpkg`, `gdebi`, `Discover...`). I used `gdebi` to pull three other dependencies. It was installed without errors.

When used with "`apt`" as a method, it is buggy (whichever level you set, it displays "`E: APT_HOOK_INFO_FD is undefined.`". There seems to be no workaround for that unless you are seriously into pinning, downgrading, and such. However, when used with the "`list`" method, it works brilliantly:

**Example of a valid one:**

```
sudo apt-listbugs -s all list man

Retrieving bug reports... Done
Parsing Found/Fixed information... Done
```

**Example of a buggy one:**

```
sudo apt-listbugs -s all list espeak

Retrieving bug reports... Done
Parsing Found/Fixed information... Done
normal bugs of espeak (→ ) <Outstanding>
 b1 - #415892 - espeak: produces incorrect length in wav headers
 b2 - #591717 - espeak: Library unble to open soundcard.
important bugs of espeak (→ ) <Forwarded>
 b3 - #822278 - espeak: not speaking german "umlaute" encoded
normal bugs of espeak (→ ) <Forwarded>
 b4 - #830731 - espeak: bad pronunciation of "unary"
minor bugs of espeak (→ ) <Forwarded>
 b5 - #946029 - espeak: inform that --stdin flag reads multi-line text 

Summary:
 espeak(5 bugs)
```

Warmly recommended for Ubuntu 20.04 since I see no issues except the inability to connect to Apt. I am about to pull every single package on my system through it with various levels of severity (and other parameters changed) and will post an edit here if it hicks up on something.

Here is the *--help* of it:

```
Usage: apt-listbugs [options] <command> [arguments]

Options:
 -s <severities>  : Filter bugs by severities you want to see
                    (or "all" for all)
                    [-D].
 -T <tags>        : Filter bugs by tags you want to see.
 -S <states>      : Filter bugs by pending-state categories you want to see
                    [pending,forwarded,pending-fixed,fixed,done].
 -B <bug#>        : Filter bugs by number, showing only the specified bugs.
 -D               : Show downgraded packages, too.
 -H <hostname>    : Hostname of Debian Bug Tracking System [bugs.debian.org].
 -p <port>        : Port number of the server [80].
 -P <priority>    : Pin-Priority value [30000].
 -E <title>       : Title of RSS output.
 -q               : Don't display progress bar.
 -C <apt.conf>    : Additional apt.conf file to use.
 -F               : Automatically pin all buggy packages.
 -N               : Never automatically pin packages.
 -y               : Assume yes for all questions.
 -n               : Assume no for all questions.
 -a               : Assume the default reply for all questions.
 -d               : Debug.
 -h               : Display this help and exit.
 -v               : Show version number and exit.
Commands:
 apt              : Apt mode.
 list <pkg>..     : List bug reports of the specified packages.
 rss <pkg>..      : List bug reports of the specified packages in RSS.
```

Comment: You do realize those bugs are not Ubuntu bugs and may not relate at all; eg. I picked on at random and it takes me to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/822278 (unrelated to your "*espeak: not speaking german "umlaute" encoded*") which you'll note does not relate.  Ubuntu uses different package builds so knowing the debian issues is only helpful if you're very aware of the stack you're both using & differences that have occurred since it left Debian (ie. it won't show if Ubuntu fixed them! & some patches come from upstream of Debian so won't show).

Comment: "Warmly recommended for Ubuntu 20.04 since I see no issues" That does not mean there are none... Ubuntu bugs need to be done through Ubuntu where they can elevate the issue to Debian.

Comment: As not to edit, I will apologize both for the bad approach and a bad example. What I'm about to do is try and modify it so it connects to Ubuntu list.