# apt pin for snapd is ignored in 22.04

Tags: apt, snap, 22.04

Issue: banning snapd from being installed by recording

```
Package: snapd
Pin: origin *
Pin-Priority: -1
```

into /etc/apt/preferences.d/snapd does not work in 22.04. (Same with Pin: release *, or a few other variations that I've tried.) This works for any other package (!?) and also worked for earlier versions of Ubuntu. What's happening, am I going crazy or have Canonical messed with apt to enforce snapd on us?

Comment: it's in a file of course, will correct the original statement as not to cause extra confusion...

Comment: btw, I "solved" the problem by banning apparmor which of course then does not allow for installation of snapd. However the question of why on earth snapd is not bannable remains...

Comment: Maybe it needs to be changed to `Pin: release *`?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/75895/how-to-forbid-a-specific-package-to-be-installed  Someone in the comments of the first answer mentioned it.

Comment: This morning, an update of a PPA installed deb version of Firefox put me back on the snap version, reinstalling snapd and all!!! So yes, something may be going on here in this respect!

Comment: @Terrance  tried that too (mentioned above ;)) -- it didn't make any difference

Comment: You probably hit a bug then.  I would file it with Canonical since it worked in previous versions.  `ubuntu-bug apt` and file showing how the Pin-Priority is not blocking the installation.